# Is it possible process a payment that goes giver to receiver, when I am neither?

Tags: paypal, payment

To be more clear. I am thinking of developing a site where someone/many could sponsor a person financially. I was thinking of using Paypal for this. I realize this assumes the receiver has a paypal account but I'll figure that out in the future.

Basically, people would come to the site find the person they want to sponsor or create an account (on my site, not paypal) for them. Then send a payment for them from my site using paypal.

Does Paypal's API support these kinds of transactions?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you going to develop a crowd funding project. i suggest paypal Adaptive Payments.

hope this will help you.

https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/adaptive-payments/integration-guide/APIntro/

Comment: Perfect! That is exactly what I needed to know.